# Interpret strings as packed binary data in C++

Tags: c++

I have question about interpreting strings as packed binary data in C++. In python, I can use struct module. Is there a module or a way in C++ to interpret strings as packed binary data without embedding Python?

Comment: A string is a sequence of contiguous characters (bytes, basically).  How much more packed do you wish to get?

Comment: So, given a byte array, you want to be able to treat the array as a `struct`? You could just use a cast.

Comment: In C++, for binary data, you would typically use a `vector` (rather than a string) and the `unsigned char` type to represent a byte (avoiding signedness issues). Thus a typical "buffer" would be of type `std::vector<unsigned char>`, rather than `std::string`... note that in C++03 the string storage need not be contiguous.

Comment: @MatthieuM. C++03 didn't require contiguity, but the C style array pointed to by the return value of `std::string::data()` must be contiguous.  And the reason C++11 added the contiguous requirement was in recognition of existing practice---there were in fact no implementations which weren't contiguous (and where `&s[0]` didn't result in the same values as `s.data()`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: `data` is for `vector`, so I believe you are talking about `c_str`. The problem with `c_str` is that it is `char const*` and sometimes you'd like to modify the characters (`to_upper` ?).

Comment: @MatthieuM. `data()` is for `string`.  It was added to `vector` in C++11, but has always been in `string`.  There was talk of adding a non-const `data()` to `string` in C++11; apparently, it got overlooked.  In general, when dealing with byte sized data, rather than text, I would prefer `vector<signed char>` or `vector<unsigned char>` (with the latter for raw memory as well)---it seems to expression the intent better---but `string` will work as well.

Comment: @MatthieuM. And `c_str()` is only for when you want a `'\0'` terminated string.  So not for packed binary data.  (Again, it will work, but it expresses a completely different intent.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: ah thanks, I had missed that (I'll be unapologetic and blame the too bloated interface of `string` ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, it is better to consider this an array of bytes (chars, or unsigned chars), possibly held in a std::vector, rather than a string.  A string is null terminated, so what happens if a byte of the binary data had the value zero?

You can either cast a pointer within the array to a pointer to your struct, or copy the data over a struct:

```
#include <memory>

#pragma pack ( push )
#pragma pack( 1 );

struct myData
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    // and whatever
};

#pragma pack ( pop ) 


char* dataStream = GetTheStreamSomehow();

    //cast the whole array
myData* ptr = reinterpret_cast<myData*>( dataStream );
    //cast from a known position within the array
myData* ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<myData*>( &(dataStream[index]) );

    //copy the array into a struct
myData data;
memcpy( &data, dataStream, sizeof(myData) );
```

If you were to have the data stream in a vector, the [] operator would still work.  The pragma pack declarations ensure the struct is single byte aligned - researching this is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

A string in C++  has a method called c_str ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ ).

c_str returns the relevant binary data in a string in form of an array of characters. You can cast these chars to anything you wish and read them as an array of numbers.

Comment: You can, although this usually lies somewhere in-between implementation-defined and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The results of the conversion will be implementation defined, since whether plain char is signed or not, and how many bits it contains, is implementation defined.  Converting a `char` to an integral type large enough to contain the value (which will be all integral types if `char` is signed) is well defined, as is converting it to any unsigned integral type or floating point type.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you don't need to interpret anything.  In C++, strings are
packed binary data; you can interpret them as text, but you're not
required to.  Just be aware that the underlying type of a string, in
C++, is `char`, which can be either signed (range `[-128,127]` on all
machines I've heard of) or unsigned (usually `[0,255]`, but I'm aware of
machines where it is `[0,511]`).

To pass the raw data in a string to a C program, use
`std::string::data()` and `std::string::size()`.  Otherwise, you can
access it using iterators or indexation much as you would with
`std::vector<char>` (which may express the intent better).

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough it might be closer to [pickling](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) in python, [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) may be closest to what you want to achieve.

Otherwise you might want to do it by hand.  It is not that hard to make reader/writer classes to convert primitives/classes to packed binary format.  I would do it by shifting bytes to avoid host endianess issues.

Comment: Thx guys for the very quickly answers.
For clarification, I want to overwrite my application with Python to C++
http://www.devpda.net/rsceditor
RSCEditor for edit EXE/DLL and RSC files and i have problems with some functions in python for example:
• builtn map()
• struct.unpack
• struct.pack
• index from to in ARRAYS (example arrary[5:15])
i don't know have can i write this in C++