# C++ Qt equivalent to python unpack_from

Tags: python, c++, qt, stream

I'm looking for a version of python unpack_from in Qt.
In Python I have got the following code to decode a stream from a serial device:

```
out = unpack_from('<HHHHHHBBBBBBBBBBHHBBHB', buf, offset=2)
```

How can this be done in C++ with Qt.

Comment: i don't really understand your question aren't you using pyqt already?

Comment: No, I want t use native Qt without python

Comment: Then your question should be tagged with c++, it's not clear this way

Answer (score 2):

There's no strict equivalent but this question on SO has some good answers on how you can approach it in C++: [Interpret strings as packed binary data in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903905/interpret-strings-as-packed-binary-data-in-c)